how do i get a random item from a list and print it to the console?
I am new to C# and cant find out how to choose a random item from my list to print, I am trying to make something similar to a random password generator, if it helps or makes a difference they are all words not numbers
here is my current code
internal class Program
{
    public static object Ram { get; private set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is a complament generator generator");
        var complamenttList = ("funny", "delightfull", "chute", "chearfull", "A22 Warthog");
    }
}

i have tried to add this onto the end
 var bag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
 bag.Add("wasd");
 bag.Add("ijkl");
 bag.Add("up down left right");
 string result;
 if (bag.TryTake(out result))
 {
    Console.WriteLine(result);
     Console.ReadLine();
 }
 if (bag.TryTake(out result))
 {
     Console.WriteLine(result);
     Console.ReadLine();
 }
 if (bag.TryTake(out result))
 {
     Console.WriteLine(result);
     Console.ReadLine();
 }

`
